# How do I mount an existing Truecrypt container on an AOSP rom like Cyanogenmod?

Tags: cyanogenmod, custom-roms, encryption

I have an existing Truecrypt container (AES encryption), how do I mount it on my AOSP rom?
I have already downloaded Cryptonite (which contains Truecrypt in command-line form) but I'm not sure what I'm meant to do next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to access TrueCrypt containers/files, you need to use 3rd party apps like [EDS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sovworks.edslite) or [Cryptonite](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=csh.cryptonite). For the latter, which you already have, follow the instructions in their [FAQ](http://code.google.com/p/cryptonite/) to mount with correct permissions:

```
truecrypt --fs-options="uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=0002" volume.tc /sdcard/tc
```